# php mail send not working

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send mails through php script.
I am trying with

```
<?php
$to = 'user@domain.com';
$subject = 'Test subject';
$message = 'Test message'; 
$from = 'user1@domain.com';
if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
} 
?>
```

On execute am getting "Your mail has been sent successfully" message but no message is received in mailbox.

What i have to do further.
My mails works on cakephp outlook configuration.But not with PHP.
I have seen related questions in stackoverflow but no use :(
Please let me know any other ways.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for sending email you need to change fue things in php.ini here are the list to do the same.
To check/change your PHP mail configuration:

1. Open your php.ini file
2. Search for the line that reads [mail function]
3. Add/change the details of your mail server. This could be a local mail server or the mail server of your ISP.
4. Save/close the php.ini file
5. Restart your web server

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your eror is: `mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing`.
Check your php.ini file and try to var_dump some variables and check where is error. As error says, "From:" header missing.